# asyns requests to api in django view

Tags: django, requests, asyncio

у меня есть джанго аппликация
и мне нужно в одной вюхе вернуть значение с одной апи
Например: человек будет заходить на страницу, будет делаться запрос к апи и возвращать значение
мне интересно надо делать запросы асинхронно? если на эту страницу будут заходить много людей
вот мой код:

```
import aiohttp
import asynsio
asyns def get_rate():
    url = 'https://api.ratesapi.io/api/latest?base=USD&symbols=GBP'
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        json_response = await response.json()
        return json_response

def test_view(request):
    usd = asyncio.run(get_rate())['ratest]["USD]
    return render(request, '???.html', {'usd':usd})
```

правильно так или нужно по другому??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный вызов асинхронного кода в Django такой

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/#async-to-sync

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import aiohttp
import asynsio

@async_to_sync
async def get_rate():
    url = 'https://api.ratesapi.io/api/latest?base=USD&symbols=GBP'
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        json_response = await response.json()
        return json_response

def test_view(request):
    usd = get_rate()['ratest]["USD]
    return render(request, '???.html', {'usd':usd})
```

Но использовать вызовы для каждого запроса - плохая идея. Используйте кеш https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/

```
from django.core.cache import cache

....

    usd = cache.get_or_set("USD", get_rate, timeout=60)['ratest]["USD]
```

Comment: а если допустим значение долара изменится?

Comment: @DartVinnie так Вы сами можете задать на сколько кешируете результат запроса. Доллар же не каждую мс обновляется)

Comment: @asanisimov ваш код с кешем использовать в test_view?

Comment: добавить ttl надо

Comment: сначала добавить асинк-ту-синк, настроить кеш в мемкешед,базу,редис или в файлы. потом использовать во вью можно

Comment: `@async_to_sync` убьёт всю асинхронность и в таком коде нет никакого смысла

Comment: @andreymal в джанге в любом случае она убивается

Comment: Ааа все понял, спасибо

Comment: @eri в django уже давно завезли асинхронщину, так что ничего не убьётся, если использовать asgi-сервер

Comment: дополню ответ если разберусь с asgi... в последнее время писал все на aiohttp сервере с рендером на клиенте